# Matplotlib: figure.add_axes convert from x,y to relative coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a self-organizing map that I want to show as a hexagonal lattice with spider charts representing the weight vector/neuron in the corresponding cells and have been able to create a hexagonal grid via the following:

```
def hex_plot(ws,a=1):
    """
     plots a m (rows) x n (cols) hexagonal grid with offset rows where a is 
     the hexagon's side length and m and n are determined by the first two 
     dimensions of the weight vectors ws
    """
    m,n,_ = ws.shape
    offsety = .75 * 2*a
    offsetx = numpy.sqrt(3) * a
    oddrow = numpy.sqrt(3)/2 * a
    x,y = 0,0

    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.5,7.5))
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_zorder(1)

    cs = {}
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            offsetr = oddrow if i % 2 != 0 else 0
            cp = (j*offsetx+offsetr,-i*offsety)
            cs[(i,j)] = cp
            hexg = RegularPolygon(cp,numVertices=6,radius=a,facecolor='white',edgecolor='k')
            ax.add_patch(hexg)
            ax.text(cp[0], cp[1], "{},{}\n{:.2f},{:.2f}".format(i,j,cp[0],cp[1]), ha='center', va='center', size=10)
    xy = [cs[(i,j)] for i in range(m) for j in range(n)]    
    ax.scatter([x for x,_ in xy],[y for _,y in xy],c='white',alpha=0.5)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    plt.show()
```

This gives me the following:
[5x4 blank hexagon grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgKmf.png)

With that I am trying to place spider charts of the neurons [5x4 trained SOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LItwL.png) representing each weight vector such that the spider chart at 0,0 (top left) is inside the hexagonal cell at 0,0 (top left). I tried using sub plots but the difficulty arises in the spider charts having a polar projections whereas the grids do not. My second attempt involves using "add_axes". By adding the following immediately prior to plt.show() in the code above:

```
w = ws[0][0] # current weight vector
a = numpy.linspace(0,2*numpy.pi,len(w),endpoint=False)
a = numpy.concatenate((a,[a[0]]))
w = numpy.concatenate((w,[w[0]]))

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.0,0.0,0.1,0.1],polar=True,zorder=2)

ax1.set_thetagrids([])    
ax1.fill(a,w,alpha=1.0)
ax1.set_yticklabels([])
ax1.set_rticks([])
```

I can place a spider chart in the lower left canvas: [Spider chart over hex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hTyc.png), But since the rectangle specified in add_axes is in coordinates relative to the figure, I cannot figure out to determine what coordinate 0,0 in the orginal axes (hexagon 0,0) would map to in relative coordinates. I looked at transformations but it wasn't helpful.

Has anyone ran into this and come up with a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options here:

## Plot all shapes in a single axes

Since it does not look like there is a need for a special polar axes you could just plot the fills all in the same axes at the respective positions of the hexagons.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import RegularPolygon


def hex_plot(ws,a=1):
    """
     plots a m (rows) x n (cols) hexagonal grid with offset rows where a is 
     the hexagon's side length and m and n are determined by the first two 
     dimensions of the weight vectors ws
    """
    m,n,l = ws.shape
    offsety = .75 * 2*a
    offsetx = np.sqrt(3) * a
    oddrow = np.sqrt(3)/2 * a
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, l+1)

    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.5,7.5))
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_zorder(1)

    cs = {}
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            offsetr = oddrow if i % 2 != 0 else 0
            cp = (j*offsetx+offsetr,-i*offsety)
            cs[(i,j)] = cp
            hexg = RegularPolygon(cp,numVertices=6,radius=a,
                                  facecolor='white',edgecolor='k')
            ax.add_patch(hexg)
            ax.text(cp[0], cp[1], "{},{}\n{:.2f},{:.2f}".format(i,j,cp[0],cp[1]), 
                    ha='center', va='center', size=10)

            r = ws[i,j,:]
            r = np.concatenate((r, [r[0]]))
            x,y = (np.c_[r*np.sin(theta), r*np.cos(theta)] + cp).T
            ax.fill(x,y, color="C0")


    ax.autoscale()
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    plt.show()


hex_plot(np.random.rand(5,4,6),a=1)
```

[image]

## Use `inset_axes`

If you really need the axes, e.g. to show the grids, you may position `inset_axes` at the respective positions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import RegularPolygon
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
from matplotlib.projections import get_projection_class

def hex_plot(ws,a=1):
    """
     plots a m (rows) x n (cols) hexagonal grid with offset rows where a is 
     the hexagon's side length and m and n are determined by the first two 
     dimensions of the weight vectors ws
    """
    m,n,l = ws.shape
    offsety = .75 * 2*a
    offsetx = np.sqrt(3) * a
    oddrow = np.sqrt(3)/2 * a
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, l+1)


    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.5,7.5))
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_zorder(1)

    cs = {}
    axcs = {}
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            offsetr = oddrow if i % 2 != 0 else 0
            cp = (j*offsetx+offsetr,-i*offsety)
            cs[(i,j)] = cp
            hexg = RegularPolygon(cp,numVertices=6,radius=a,
                                  facecolor='white',edgecolor='k')
            ax.add_patch(hexg)
            ax.text(cp[0], cp[1], "{},{}\n{:.2f},{:.2f}".format(i,j,cp[0],cp[1]), 
                    ha='center', va='center', size=10)

            axins=inset_axes(ax, width="100%", height="100%", 
                             bbox_to_anchor=(cp[0]-offsetx/2, cp[1]-offsety/2, offsetx, offsety),
                             bbox_transform=ax.transData, borderpad=0, 
                             axes_class=get_projection_class("polar"),
                             )
            axins.set_zorder(4)
            axcs[(i,j)] = axins

            r = ws[i,j,:]
            r = np.concatenate((r, [r[0]]))
            axins.fill(theta,r)

            axins.set_yticklabels([])
            axins.set_xticklabels([])


    ax.autoscale()
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    plt.show()


hex_plot(np.random.rand(5,4,6),a=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I figured I was nuking it instead of going simple first