# Inset_axes in polar coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes` (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html) to create an child axe of a an existing parent axe.

How do I set it to polar coordinates ?
I can not use this: [Matplotlib inset polar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610973/matplotlib-inset-polar-plot?noredirect=1&lq=1) as  `'Axes' object has no property 'polar'`.

But `inset_axes` only returns `Axes` objects and not `projections.polar.PolarAxes` ..

Comment: Here are two other questions to consider: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204267/matplotlib-figure-add-axes-convert-from-x-y-to-relative-coordinates/53210818#53210818) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262749/plotting-scatter-of-several-polar-plots/46263911#46263911). Both use polar plots on inset axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment of ImportanceOfBeingErnest:

just use `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes()` instead, with the parameter `axes_class = matplotlib.projections.get_projection_class('polar')`.

Answer (score 0):

From [version 3.6](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases/tag/v3.6.0), matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes also accepts "polar" and "projection" parameters, so the original version of your code will work in the latest versions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33086489)