# inset_axes polar projection in a polar plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, zooming, polar-coordinates

I would like to create a polar plot with a polar zoom.
This is what I have done do far:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))
G = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)

axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[0],projection='polar')

axes_1.inset_axes(bounds=[0.0,0.0,0.1,0.1],projection='polar')


axes_2 = plt.subplot(G[1])
```

and here the error that I get:

```
'Axes' object has no property 'projection'
```

This is quite strange, because in the manual of inset_axes I have found the option projection ([here](https://proplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/proplot.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html)).

There are some attempts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595212/inset-axes-in-polar-coordinates), but for me is totally unclear, or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54395307/how-to-add-a-wedge-sector-onto-a-polar-matplotlib-plot), but this last it is not what I what. It is just another plot.

Thanks

Comment: That's the ProPlot docs, right?

Comment: Does it  not refer to matplolib?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html

Comment: it seens that there is no "polar" option. Am I right? How i could overcome this problem?

Comment: @diedro, does [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html) answer your question

Comment: Not really. It refers to the standard polar plot. I would like to have it in a zoom region.

Answer (score 0):

From [version 3.6](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases/tag/v3.6.0), matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes accepts "polar" and "projection" parameters. If you use a older version, there is also a workaround using mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes() (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595212/inset-axes-in-polar-coordinates)).

Creating a rectangular zoom of a polar plot is not as straightforward, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74267208/8159852) may help you.